# Showing that $\dfrac{q^n -1}{(q-1)\gcd(n,q-1)}$ is an integer for $q = p^k$, $p$ prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

> Does anyone know how to prove that $\dfrac{q^n -1}{(q-1)\gcd(n,q-1)}$ is an integer for $q = p^k$, $p$ prime using only basic algebra?

It is possible to show this by showing that there is a subgroup $C$ of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}^*$ such that $ \#C = (q-1)\gcd(n,q-1)$, but is it possible to find a simpler proof?

Answer (score 4):

In modulo $\gcd(n,q-1)$ we have:

\begin{align*}
\frac{q^n-1}{q-1} & = q^{n-1} + \cdots + q + 1 \\
& = 1 + \cdots + 1 + 1 \\
& \equiv n \ \equiv  \ 0
\end{align*}

Comment: is the condition $q=p^k$ necessary ?

Comment: @GCab I haven't noticed that. Well, it seems we don't need that condition, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: $\gcd(q,a)=1$ with $a=\gcd(n,q-1)$?

Comment: @Maman yes. Because of its definition, in modulo $a$ we have $q-1\equiv 0$ which implies $q \equiv 1$. Hence $\gcd(q,a)=1$.

Comment: in fact, it seems also to me that it is superfluous: $gcd(q,q-1)=1$ for all $q$